# alternative for inline-block for ie7

Tags: html, internet-explorer-7, css

for my website, im using inline-block property. it works well for mozilla and ie8 but is displayed as block elements in ie7. how can i set it right?

Comment: This may help you [link](http://www.w3schools.com/css/pr_class_display.asp)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Have a look at this: http://foohack.com/2007/11/cross-browser-support-for-inline-block-styling/ - at this point in time, IE8 was not out yet, so I believe the author is talking about IE7.

Comment: in short, just add `- zoom:1; *display:inline;`