# HTML/CSS: Input element weird indent ie7

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer-7

http://jsfiddle.net/vol7ron/yHdr6/

The INPUT is taking the margin-left from the ancestor DIV.
Setting the margin of the parent DIV/SPAN/INPUT has no effect (unless I missed one).

---

#### HTML

---

```
<form>
   <div id="contact_info">
      <div><span>Name:  </span></div>
      <div><span>Email: </span></div>
      <div><span>Phone: </span></div>
      <div>
         <label for="email">Owner Email: </label>
         <span class="ib">
            <input type="text" name="email" id="email"/><br />
            <span>(correct if needed)</span>
         </span>
      </div>
   </div>
</form>
```

---

#### CSS

---

```
span.ib { 
    border         : 1px solid red;  /* for debugging */
    display        : inline-block; 
    vertical-align : top; 
} 

#contact_info {
    border         : 1px solid #ccc; 
    margin         : 1em 2em; 
    padding        : 1em;
}

/* Debugging Attempts *
.ib,input {
    clear:left;
    display:inline-block;
    margin:0em 0em !important;
    left:0;
    padding:0em 0em !important;
    position:relative;
    text-align:left;
    text-indent:0 !important;
}/**/
```

Comment: Inline-block is buggie in IE7. look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4988727/alternative-for-inline-block-for-ie7) for a solution

Comment: @nuc: I thought that this was one of the things that IE actually adhered to the standard - don't quote me on that, though.  I also vaguely remember that applying an inline-block to a `span` is better than applying it to a `div`. It could be the reverse - it's been a while since I've touched styling - but the point is, one works as it should, while the other doesn't.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So after trying two more things, I found that adding either `zoom:1` or `display:inline-block;` to the input's parent DIV (not the SPAN), will remove this weird indent.  Thus, it's another `hasLayout` problem.

I have not found out why setting the margin does not fix it and I've forgotten the rules as to when Internet Explorer inherits the properties from parent vs sibling.

Answer (score 1):

I'd always make sure that you include a CSS reset to avoid such problems. Eric Meyer's is widely regarded as a good one to use, though it isn't the only one.

http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/

Comment: +1, I've developed some of my own reset/default properties, but didn't think to apply it here.  This is someone else's old code that I'm updating.  Had I applied this, I think it would have fixed the hasLayout issue.

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't actually inherit a margin. `display: inline-block;` on the parent div is causing the input element within it to be `offset left` the amount of the margin from the `div#contact_info`. This is different than `margin-left` and is related to `hasLayout`.

You have a couple of choices for a fix:

1. Remove `inline-block` from the span and find another way (like putting a description under the label).
2. add `position: relative; left: -2em;` to the input using an IE7 stylesheet. This makes more sense than using zoom since, in the future, people may not understand the effect. However, it is obvious that a bug is being fixed with the browser that causes the input position to be shifted and that you are compensating for it.
3. use `zoom`, please don't. Adding `zoom:1` to the parent `div#contact_info` doesn't even connect to the problem at hand other than `hasLayout` being the problem. Additionally, Safari and IE support zoom as a css attribute, thus this may cause other issues in the future.

Comment: Do you have any quick recommendations for #1?  For #2, I like to avoid the overhead associated with browser-specific stylesheets, but even if you use that method, you'll have to include comments to know why this was applied in IE anyhow (thus `zoom:1` is more concise) - I think Rich's solution would be easier to follow w/ proper comments.  For #3, the problem is `hasLayout`, thus `zoom:1` would be a better trick.  However, there is an option #4, which I chose to use and that's adding `inline-block` to the closest parent DIV.